# zsh: command not found: rvm-prompt

Tags: rvm, zsh

After I remove `rvm` (ruby version manager), the zsh aways came out:

```
zsh: command not found: rvm-prompt
```

Is there something I did not clear?
But I had remove all of `rvm` files and script in `zshrc` or `bash_profile` ...

Answer (score 8):

It seems that you are using a theme which uses rvm-prompt like "fino-time".

Comment: I started getting the error straight after changing to this theme.

Comment: @ShaneJones so did you fix it or is there something that i can help :)

Answer (score 3):

from the looks of it, you might be calling that command from your prompt definition.

Your `.zshrc` or `.zshenv` is likely sourcing `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` (which you do not want to do anymore, now that you removed it from your system)

Comment: we have to delete $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ? how ?